How to assign value to column based on value of another column and save this value in subsequent rows
I have a table 'FileString', with columns 'Value' and 'BGM':



Value
BGM




UNA



UNB



BGM+08



UNA



UNB



UNB



BGM+10



UNB



UNA



UNB




I would like to update the table and assign BGM the value of the last two charecters. The BGM column should keep the value in sebsequent rows, until BGM changes.
Like this:



Value
BGM




UNA



UNB



BGM+08
08


UNA
08


UNB
08


UNB
08


BGM+10
10


UNB
10


UNA
10


UNB
10



Is this possible?
Thank you
The following only updates the rows with 'BGM'. It doesn't save the value in the next rows:
Update #Filestring
Set 
[BGM] = RIGHT(Value,2)
Where CHARINDEX('BGM+', Value) > 0
;


Please edit your question to explain sebsequent rows when you have no ORDER BY here. #Filestring is a temp table; please share where you define that and where you insert into that as code perhaps.  Keep in mind that SQL works with "sets" of data not "rows of data" thus you need to order by something that is not apparent in you current example data or code

Aren't the "last two characters" in 'UNB' 'NB'?
